# Ubuntu Server 16.04 ismissing enp3s0 section in ifconfig

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, dhcp, ip-address

This morning our server encountered an error. The IP Add was changed to dhcp, and I tried to set it as a static IP, the one we reserved for the server to be accessible by the local network. After setting the ip addr from dhcp changing to static enp3s0 is missing in the `ifconfig` command.

[image]

Comment: Consider to add `ifconfig -a`. And check the status of Ethernet cards in  BIOS. Do you know manufacturer and model of Ethernet card?

Comment: entered the command ifconfig -a shows the port/s, enp3s0, lo, virb0, virbr0-nic. Unfortunately idk the model and manufacturer of Ethernet Card.

Comment: An Asus P8H61-M MOBO sir. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: it is now up I used ip link set dev enp3s0 up. it worked, but i cant ping google or set my ip add. Please help me. Thank you. It is now blinking.

Comment: Follow https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf about Network Configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I redid everything to better understand the whole network. Because we have 2 internet provide with different ISPs/IPs. Figured it out tho. Thanks

Comment: To have this question closed I added the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. understand the relation between your ISPs and IPs
2. follow https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf about *Network Configuration* to set it up correctly